# ASP.NET MVC: Dowloading data as a file to local computer. SAve As dialog

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, download, upload

I generate a xml dynamically (serializing my custom type XMLDocType) in an ASP.NET MVC3 through the code below:

```
XMLDocType XMLdoc = new XMLDocType();
… generating contente for XMLdoc … 
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLDocType));

TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("xmloutput.xml");

xml.Serialize(writer, XMLdoc);

writer.Close();
```

How can I dowload the xml content into the local computer (instead of server) through the normal downloading process in browsers (ie, opening a Save As dialog)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this class that extends `ActionResult` and return it in your MVC action. Also you write to `MemoryStream` instead of writing to local server file, and return it to user as response from Controller action.

```
public class FileResult : ActionResult
{
    public String ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
    public String SourceFilename { get; set; }

    public FileResult(byte[] sourceStream, String contentType, String sourceFilename)
    {
        FileBytes = sourceStream;
        SourceFilename = sourceFilename;
        ContentType = contentType;
    } 
}

public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{   
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(); 
    XMLDocType XMLdoc = new XMLDocType();
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLDocType));
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
    xml.Serialize(writer, XMLdoc);

    FileResult file = new FileResult(memoryStream.ToArray(), "text/xml", "MyXMLFile.xml");

    writer.Close();

    return file;
}
```

Comment: In the controller I do like below:

// export to .xml here!
            ExportXMLModel e = new ExportXMLModel();

            return e.DoExportXML(o.oTable);

and the code doesn't function. No Save As dialog opens in Edge and Chrome, and I don't know where the file is saved….

Comment: … the DoExportXML does the same thing as Kenan's DownloadFile...